# How to create a PLY yacc read arrays?

Tags: python, ply

I'm writing a compiler in Python for my own language. I wrote the lexer and now for the parser I don't know how to make yacc read multiple commas.

Syntax for arrays: [something,something else]

Comment: Do you know how to write a grammar for multiple statements? How about multiple operators? If not, have you looked at any of the sample grammars in the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Examples) or picked up a book on the subject?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.